# Python C API: PyEval_CallFunction?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I've discovered a function in the Python C API named `PyEval_CallFunction` which seems to be useful.  It allows you to invoke a Python callable by saying something like:

```
PyEval_CallFunction(obj, "OOO", a, b, c);
```

However, I can't find any official documentation on this function.  A google search brings up various [*unofficial* tutorials](http://starship.python.net/crew/mwh/toext/calling-python-from-c.html) which discuss this function, but:

1. The function [isn't
   documented](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/search.html?q=PyEval_CallFunction&check_keywords=yes&area=default) in the official
   Python docs, so I don't know if it's
   even something that is supposed to
   be part of the public API.
2. Searching the web turns up
       inconsistent usage policies.  Some
       tutorials indicate the
       format string needs parenthesis
       around the type list, like
       `"(OiiO)"`, whereas other times I
       see it used without the parenthesis.
       When I actually try the function in
       a real program, it seems to require
       the parenthesis, otherwise it
       segfaults.

I'd like to use this function because it's convenient.  Does anyone know anything about this, or know why it [isn't documented](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/search.html?q=PyEval_CallFunction&check_keywords=yes&area=default)?  Is it part of the public API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find many references to it either, but the tutorial you linked to mentions this:

> The string format and the following
>   arguments are as for Py_BuildValue
>   (XXX so i really should have described
>   that by now!). A call such as
>
> ```
> PyEval_CallFunction(obj, "iii", a, b, c);
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> PyEval_CallObject(obj, Py_BuildValue("iii", a, b, c));
> ```

I suppose `PyEval_CallFunction` is not public API, as its value seems rather limited. There is not much of a difference between these two. But then again, I'm not really involved in python extensions, so this is just my view on this.

`PyEval_CallObject` itself is just a macro around `PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords`.

```
#define PyEval_CallObject(func,arg) \
        PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(func, arg, (PyObject *)NULL)
```

---

On the matter of "What is public API?" here is a recent message from Martin v. Löwis:

> Just to stress and support Georg's
>   explanation: the API is *not* defined
>   through the documentation, but instead
>   primarily through the header files.
>   All functions declared as PyAPI_FUNC
>   and not starting with _Py are public
>   API. There used to be a lot of undocumented API (up to 1.4, there was no API documentation at all, only the extension module tutorial); these days, more and more API gets documented.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2011-February/107973.html

Comment: Note that, in the context of Martin's message, being "public" refers to APIs that we won't alter or remove without going through a deprecation process first. It doesn't mean calling an undocumented API is a good idea when a documented alternative is available. In the case of `PyEval_CallFunction`, the documented (and preferred) API is `PyObject_CallFunction` which includes additional steps that `PyEval_CallFunction` assumes have already been dealt with by the calling code.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it isn't documented is because you should be using [PyObject_CallFunction](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_call#PyObject_CallFunction) instead.

The `PyEval_*` function family are the raw internal calls for the interpreter evaluation loop. The corresponding documented `PyObject_*` calls include all the additional interpreter state integrity checks, argument validation and stack protection.